# Debugging on Android hardware not in OEM list

Tags: android, debugging

I've got a PendoPad Android device that's not on the OEM list that I want to debug an app on. I've taken the time to read the Android development site, but my device isn't listed on the OEM list.

I've got Eclipse on Windows 7 installed, and I've run my application on an emulator.

I run the adb.exe devices, and though I can see my "phone" and its files in Windows Explorer, the adb list is empty.

Has anyone encountered and surmounted this issue?

Comment: Did you enable the development function on the phone? Did you install the correct drivers? (it could be just listed in explorer as a mass storage device)

Comment: Read the android development site. You need the device drivers installed onto your OS before calling adb.

Comment: +1 What @Nanne said -- also, if you can see the "files in Windows Explorer", you're definitely not running the USB connection in developer mode.

Comment: Here's the trick mates. What drivers?  If you say for my OEM, i'm have to reach through the screen and smack ya'll.  :)  My devices isn't listed in the OEM list.  Saying you have to install the drivers is funny.. (though tragic) Where does one get said drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this with an Archos device.

You need to add device ID into list of ADB supported devices.

The file to modify is this: %USERPROFILE%.android\adb_usb.ini

[Here's Archos advice about this.](http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html?country=us&lang=en)

Now you just need to determine your device's vendor ID. And this seems to be written in Device manager, when you click details of your Android device, Details tab, Hardware Ids property. There's something like USB\VID_0E79&PID_1411&REV_0216&MI_01, where 0E79 is vendor id of Archos.
Find our your ID and append it to the adb_usb.ini file. Restart adb and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux:**

Write `lsusb`

Sample output for Nexus4:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 18d1:XXXX Google Inc. Nexus 4 (debug) <------ 18d1 here it is!
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Not listed OEM device aka tablet no_name:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 2207:0010  <------------------------------ here it is 2207
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So next you should edit `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` as they say [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)

So in my example i must add something like this:

```
#FunTab8
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

For me it works now ADB after using `adb devices`

```
List of devices attached 
NCGS6FX7U5  device
```

If you want here is my full list:

```
#FunTab8
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Acer   0502
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#ASUS   0b05
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Dell   413c
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Foxconn    0489
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Fujitsu    04c5
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Fujitsu Toshiba    04c5
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Garmin-Asus    091e
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Google 18d1
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Haier  201E
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="201E", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Hisense    109b
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="109b", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#HTC    0bb4
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Huawei 12d1
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Intel  8087
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="8087", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#K-Touch    24e3
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#KT Tech    2116
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Kyocera    0482
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Lenovo 17ef
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#LG 1004
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Motorola   22b8
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#MTK    0e8d
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#NEC    0409
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Nook   2080
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Nvidia 0955
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#OTGV   2257
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Pantech    10a9
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Pegatron   1d4d
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Philips    0471
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#PMC-Sierra 04da
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Qualcomm   05c6
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#SK Telesys 1f53
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Samsung    04e8
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sharp  04dd
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sony   054c
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sony Ericsson  0fce
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Sony Mobile Communications 0fce
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Teleepoch  2340
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2340", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#Toshiba    0930
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
#ZTE    19d2
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```